# Faster constant-time string comparison in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to compare an authentication token supplied by a user with an authentication token stored on my server.

The most obvious way to do this is just to use `==`, but that potentially creates a timing attack.

To mitigate that I wrote this secure comparison function:

```
# string comparison that leaks no information about the strings.
# loosely based on https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/utils.rb
# and http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/49849/timing-safe-string-comparison-avoiding-length-leak
def secure_compare(a, b)
  l = a.unpack("C*")

  i = 0
  r |= a.length - b.length # fail if the lengths are different
  b.each_byte do |v|
    r |= v ^ l[i]
    i = (i + 1) % a.length # make sure we compare on all bytes of b, even if a is shorter.
  end
  r == 0
end
```

The only problem is that this is *really* slow: it adds 180ms to a 60-80ms page load.

Is there a faster way to do constant time string comparisons? Is there a more standardised way to do it?

EDIT: I'm using the following script to benchmark different solutions, fwiw - https://gist.github.com/daxtens/a3a59f163f08f9b447bb - it shows how `==` can bail out early, leaking information, and how `secure_compare` is several orders of magnitude slower than `==`.

EDIT 2: Just to be perfectly clear, what I am trying to achieve is a function `secure_compare(secret, untrusted_input)`, where the time taken to execute depends entirely on `untrusted_input`, and not on `secret`. I also want this function to be no more than a couple of orders of magnitude worse than `==`. The provided function has the desired timing dependency, but it's way too slow.

Comment: The original string comparison will be an unmeasurably tiny proportion of that 60ms page load...

Comment: Looks pretty darn close to [how Devise does it](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise.rb#L481).  Do you know you have a problem you need to optimize?  Isn't the point to take a little while?

Comment: The point is to take the same amount of time regardless of the string contents. == will bail out at the first different character, allowing you to (in theory!) distinguish 'abcdefg' == 'abcdefh' and 'abcdefg' == 'bbcdefg'. It'd be nice if it wasn't so many orders of magnitude slower.

Comment: @NickVeys: no, the point is to take a constant amount of time independent of how many characters are identical. You still want to save money on power and cooling, i.e. use as few CPU cycles as possible.

Comment: It seems to me that if speed is an issue, then `return false if a.length != b.length` would be faster than assigning to `r` then looping over the strings before finally checking to see if `r == 0`.

Comment: If I bail out early on different lengths, it will become theoretically possible to determine the length of the secret string.

Comment: There are many more important things to worry about than timing attack over network, such as not to store the original passwords in favor of their SHA512 values

Comment: I'm not storing a password: think more along the lines of AWS authentication tokens.

Comment: If you're serious, is there any reason to not push this down into C?

Comment: @phs: I'm seriously considering that. I was kind of hoping it already existed and my Google-fu was failing me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### secure_compare (constant time string comparison in Rails)

---

If you are using Rails (or a standalone ActiveSupport) you can consider using [ActiveSupport::SecurityUtils.secure_compare](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/SecurityUtils.html#method-c-secure_compare) for the constant time string comparison.

Here is an example:

```rb
ActiveSupport::SecurityUtils.secure_compare('foo', 'bar')
```

Also if you are interested in on how it works, please have a look at the [source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/fe76a95b0d252a2d7c25e69498b720c96b243ea2/activesupport/lib/active_support/security_utils.rb#L26).

Comment: This could still be pretty slow due to the hashing, but I'm going to set it as the accepted answer because I stopped maintaining the gem years ago.

Answer (score 7):

To make things fast while keeping them simple, I've reimplemented the function in C, and [made it available as a gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/fast_secure_compare).

The source is on GitHub (https://github.com/daxtens/fast_secure_compare), but the crux of it is the following very simple C routine.

```
int secure_compare_bytes(const unsigned char * secret, unsigned int secret_len, 
                     const unsigned char * input, unsigned int input_len) {

    int input_pos;
    int secret_pos = 0;
    int result = secret_len - input_len;
    // make sure our time isn't dependent on secret_len, and only dependent
    // on input_len
    for (input_pos = 0; input_pos < input_len; input_pos++) {
        result |= input[input_pos] ^ secret[secret_pos];
        secret_pos = (secret_pos + 1) % secret_len;
    }

    return result;
}
```

```

There's also a bit of FFI glue to get it to talk to Ruby.

It's much faster than the original pure Ruby, and is somewhat faster (and much simpler) than hashing. I have edited out rehearsals for brevity. This is on a 2008 MacBook. You can replicate this with `timing.rb` in the demo directory.

```
==== Long text ====
                                         user     system      total        real
==, early fail                       0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000028)
==, late fail                        0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000710)
Pure Ruby secure_compare, 'early'    1.730000   0.040000   1.770000 (  1.777258)
Pure Ruby secure_compare, 'late'     1.730000   0.050000   1.780000 (  1.774144)
C-based FastSecureCompare, 'early'   0.040000   0.000000   0.040000 (  0.047612)
C-based FastSecureCompare, 'late'    0.040000   0.000000   0.040000 (  0.045767)
SHA512-then-==, 'early'              0.050000   0.000000   0.050000 (  0.048569)
SHA512-then-==, 'late'               0.050000   0.000000   0.050000 (  0.046100)

==== Short text ====
                                         user     system      total        real
==, early fail                       0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000028)
==, late fail                        0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000031)
Pure Ruby secure_compare, 'early'    0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.010552)
Pure Ruby secure_compare, 'late'     0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.010805)
C-based FastSecureCompare, 'early'   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000556)
C-based FastSecureCompare, 'late'    0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000516)
SHA512-then-==, 'early'              0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000780)
SHA512-then-==, 'late'               0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000812)
```

Comment: Interesting using a Gem to speed up something. +1. It should have been obvious but I had always been thinking that only Perl or Python can do that.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a faster way to do constant time string comparisons?

It is obvious that "constant time string comparison" is theoretically impossible when the input size is unlimited.  You were almost aware of that when you used `'The sly fox' * 1000` as your test input rather than `'abc'`.

> I wrote this secure comparison function

I feel bad smell here;  why don't you just use existing authentication algorithms/implementations which endured the trial of time?

> EDIT: I'm using the following script to benchmark different solutions

FYI: because module initialization etc might impact the result, it's nice to use `Benchmark.bmbm`.

Anyways how do you like this way?

```
require 'digest/sha2'

def secure_compare_kai(a, b)
    return Digest::SHA512.digest(a) == Digest::SHA512.digest(b) && a == b
end
```

Actually calculating the hash on the fly potentially leaks timing information to the attacker.  You should store the pair of the original, eh, auth token and its hash value.  Adding a grain of salt is also recommended:

- https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm

You might want to insert something like `sleep(Random.rand(10e-3..30e-3))` for your peace of mind.

### Update on performance

On my Atom D510 (1.6 GHz) machine, hashing a 1 MB input with `Digest::SHA512` took only 10 ms.

```
irb(main):009:0> x = "A" * 10**3; y = "A" * 10**6; 0
=> 0                   

irb(main):011:0> Benchmark.bmbm{|b| b.report("1 KB"){ Digest::SHA512.digest(x) }; b.report("1 MB"){ Digest::SHA512.digest(y) } }
Rehearsal ----------------------------------------
1 KB   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000049)
1 MB   0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.009677)
------------------------------- total: 0.010000sec

           user     system      total        real
1 KB   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000079)
1 MB   0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.009731)

irb(main):012:0> RUBY_VERSION
=> "2.1.2"
```

Comment: I have tried with `Benchmark.bmbm`; it didn't seem to affect the results. While I appreciate the good theoretical underpinnings behind hashing, that'll be even slower still, which is the opposite direction to where I'm trying to go.

Comment: Is there any reason to use random sleep time over a constant one? My hunch is that, if you use random time, then its min must be longer than the max time it takes for the algorithm, which makes the average sleeping time worse than if it were just a constant.

Comment: @sewa Because I like it.  Crypto researchers would laugh at both of them anyways.

Comment: What is the way that crypto researchers would not laugh at?

Comment: I guess what matters is constant time against stored password, not against input.

Comment: @dja see my update on the performance.  Do you still think SHA512 is way too slow?  When the network potion takes 60-80 ms?

Comment: @VictorMoroz yeah, that's why I recommended the OP to store hash value in addition to the original "auth token"

Comment: Now you're doing a raw comparison of hash values. That's still bad - a lot of the early timing attacks were against HMACs (http://rdist.root.org/2010/07/19/exploiting-remote-timing-attacks/). Indeed you'll find a lot of the frameworks that have a secure_compare function use it specifically for comparing hashes: https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/utils.rb#L418

Comment: As long as SHA512 is weak collision resistant, even leaking the full hash value should not practically help the attacker, provided that it's properly salted.  But if you are still concerned about timing analysis, you can apply your `secure_compare` to compare hash values.  SHA512 is only 64 bytes long.  Again, remember to hash the auth token when you store it to the DB, not on the fly.

Comment: Ah yes, you are right about hash functions. (As an aside, the auth token comes out of an environment variable, not a DB.)

However, I'm really looking for an efficient way to do constant time string comparisons - just a simple byte-by-byte comparison - without invoking lots of other magic.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may work (it's constant time against `pass`)

```
def check(x, pass)
  ((x.length > pass.length ? x : pass)
      .take(x.length)
      .zip(x)
      .reduce(true) { |r, (y, z)| r & (y == z) }) & 
  (pass.length == x.length)
end
```

On my computer it takes 0.5ms for 1000-character long password.

Comment: Won't `r & (y == z)` short-circuit if `r == false`?

Comment: Nope, `&` won't short-circuit, `&&` will. Simple check: `false & raise` vs `false && raise`

Comment: The original complaint by the OP was that his code was too slow (180 ms) for the input of 390,000 bytes long.  Your code seems to be as *slow* as the OP's (but I personally don't think the OP should worry about such a case;  too long inputs should simply be rejected.)